# ASP.NET O meu JavaScript não está a dar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Olá, estou a utilizar Javascript que serve para criar uma numeração numa TextArea quando a tecla Enter é pressionada, um exemplo :

```
1. Olá
2. Isto é isto
3. Fim
```

Este JavaScript, no entanto, não está a funcionar e eu não sei porquê, aqui está o JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#num").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.which != 13)
      return;
    var elm = $(this);
    var lines = elm.val().split("\n");
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
      lines[i] = lines[i].replace(/(\d+\.\s|^)/, (i + 1) + ". ");
      elm.val(lines.join("\n"));
    });
</script>
```

E este é o código da TextArea:

```
<textarea id="num" rows="5" cols="32">1. </textarea>
```

Não está a funcionar e eu já tentei várias coisas, sei que, no entanto, o código funciona, porque fui a um compilador online e estava a correr perfeitamente.

Comment: Estás a carregar o jQuery na página? E esse JavaScript está depois do HTML?

Comment: Sim, o Jquery está carregado na página e está depois do HTML

Comment: Algum erro na consola?

Comment: Não, nenhum erro na consola.

Comment: Percebeste porque o código da resposta aceite funcionou e o teu não?

Comment: Sim percebi, só tem um pequeno erro a ver com uma falta de ")" e de um ";", mas agora surgiu outro problema, o meu javascript não funciona se a TextArea tiver a tag runatserver="true", eu preciso desta tag na box.

Comment: Onde estava esse erro no código da pergunta? O código está com sintaxe válida e não vejo nenhum erro...

Comment: @LINQ à parte de que a resposta não resolve nenhum problema específico, não :) Ou seja: é uma resposta com boas sugestões, código válido, mas parece-me que tenta acertar no problema e não sabendo qual é o problema.

Comment: No final ele tem "}", ele tinha que pôr "});"

Comment: Mas agora estou com um problema maior, o javascript não reconhece a TextArea se esta tiver uma tag de runatserver

Comment: Leandro: "_No final ele tem "}", ele tinha que pôr "});"_ - quem é "ele"? o teu código ou na resposta?

Comment: @Sergio Na verdade eu sabia porque sei como funciona a ordem das coisas no ASP.NET. Claro que isso não está especificado na pergunta, mas tudo dá a entender que o AP não mudou essa ordem natural das coisas. Então, não é só um chute.

Comment: @LINQ seria bom referir isso na resposta. Pois o AP talvez não saiba isso...

Comment: @Sergio Se você ver na minha resposta me refiro a isso quando eu falo justamente em "inscrever o evento somente depois do elemento ter sido criado". Não falei especificamente em ASP.NET  porque não cabe, funciona assim pra qualquer coisa. É claro que a pergunta é confusa e tende a causar problemas, mas era, de certa forma, "respondível". Pra todo efeito, já excluí a minha resposta.

Comment: @LINQ eu também acho que é "respondivel". Tentei perceber se o AP percebe o problema e o que resolve o problema. Como não foi o caso, e o AP aceitou uma resposta sem explicação, achei melhor fechar.  Se achares (acharem) que agi mal podem comentar e/ou votar para reabrir. Acho que o  conjunto pergunta/resposta aceite está pouco útil e estou na esperança que a pergunta/resposta ainda venham a melhorar.

Comment: Pois é, a situação piorou com os comentários ainda. Acho que é o caso de deixar fechada mesmo. Eu só comentei isso pra dizer que minha resposta não foi um chute ao léu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ver a respota do @LINQ mais bem explicada.

tenta colocar no assim

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#num").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.which != 13)
      return;
    var elm = $(this);
    var lines = elm.val().split("\n");
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
      lines[i] = lines[i].replace(/(\d+\.\s|^)/, (i + 1) + ". ");
      elm.val(lines.join("\n"));
    });
});
```

Comment: Podes explicar porque este código resolve o problema do AP? Em particular relacionando ao comentário [_"o jQuery está depois do HTML"_](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/214294/asp-net-o-meu-javascript-n%c3%a3o-est%c3%a1-a-dar#comment438167_214294)

Comment: Minha intenção era falar só para colocar dentro de um $(document).ready(function () { }); o código que por ventura poderia funcionar não sou metre no stackoverFlow e também estou no meio do trabalho

Comment: Bruno, e pelos vistos resolveste o problema :) Eu gostava só que ficasse claro **o que** foi a diferênça porque isso resolve o problema.

Comment: Bom eu também gostaria e a responta do @LINQ completa pena que deletou. poderia ajudar alguém no futuro.

Comment: Concordo :) E fiquei surpreso a tua resposta (que aparentemente útil para o AP) ter sido aceite e a dele não. Daí que fiquei com a sensação que o AP não percebe o problema que tem, nem a sua solução.

Comment: Obrigado @LINQ você entendo do que fala. Eu estou começando nesse mundo do vicio em café.

Answer (score 5):

Lembre-se de inserir o jQuery na página e de rodar o *script* apenas depois de já ter carregado o HTML. Pois o código, propriamente dito, funciona perfeitamente - veja no final da resposta o exemplo executável.

Você disse na pergunta que está usando ASP.NET, então, o problema deve ser com a ordem das coisas. Perceba que o *script* está adicionando um *listener* para o evento *keyup* de um elemento da sua página e, para que isso funcione corretamente, é preciso que este *listener* seja vinculado **depois que o elemento HTML tenha sido criado**. Pois não faz nenhum sentido adicionar um evento a um elemento inexistente, certo?

Quase sempre, em ASP.NET, os *scripts* são definidos dentro uma seção que fica no final da página, porém, estes *scripts*, geralmente são "renderizados" pela *view engine* **antes do HTML** - isso é definido na página "master" do *layout*.

Uma maneira interessante de contornar este efeito indesejado é colocar o código dentro de `$(document).ready()`, para ter certeza que a tentativa de registrar o evento só será feita depois que o elemento já tiver sido criado. Algo como:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#num").keyup(function (event) {
        // Seu código
    });
});
```

Outro possível problema, também relacionado com a "ordem das coisas", é se o elemento foi criado dinamicamente, via JavaScript.

Neste caso, é necessário "escutar" por um evento no *body*, tendo como *target* (destino) o elemento. Por exemplo:

```
$('body').on('keyup', '#num', function (event) {
    // Seu código
});
```

Exemplo executável do seu código:

```js
$("#num").keyup(function (event) {
  if (event.which != 13)
    return;
  var elm = $(this);
  var lines = elm.val().split("\n");
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    lines[i] = lines[i].replace(/(\d+\.\s|^)/, (i + 1) + ". ");
  }
  
  elm.val(lines.join("\n"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="num" rows="5" cols="32">1. </textarea>
```